# How to calculate this angle

Tags: trigonometry

I already spent the last 4 hours trying to work out this solution which probably is very very simple but I cant find it.

I am building a 2D printer which works like this image:

[image]

MOTOR1 spins the BLACK PLATE and the MOTOR2 spins the yellow plate in precise angles. I have the point (1,1) in the BLACK PLATE and I need to rotate both motors in order to get the BLUE DOT to touch this coordinate (1,1).

Considering that the yellow bar is initially all perfectly vertically and the black plate is in the "standard" position, how much must I rotate the BLACK PLATE (in radians or degrees) and how much must I rotate the YELLOW BAR (in radians or degrees) in order to get this to work?

Comment: What is the center point of the yellow bar in terms of coordinates? The black one is at (0,0), but what is the yellow one centered at? And what is the distance between the center point and the blue dot?

Comment: Thank you for helping. The yellow bar is rotated at (0,A). The blue dot is the "tool" which has to make contact with the point at (1,1)

Comment: Are you sure about that? The image doesn't agree with the yellow bar being centered at (A,0). Are you saying the black dot of the yellow bar starts at (A,0)?

Comment: @Mitch yes, the image shows that the yellow bar is rotated at (A,0): x being at A and y at 0. I dont know why are you confused but as I see it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

When the blue dot coincides with the point $(1,1)$, you'll have a triangle with side lengths $A$, $B$, and $\sqrt 2$. If $\alpha$ denotes the angle opposite side $A$ and $\beta$ denotes the angle opposite side $B$ and $\gamma$ denotes the angle opposite the third side (the one with length $\sqrt 2$), then  the yellow bar needs to rotate by $\frac\pi 2 - \gamma$ radians. As for the black plate, it needs to move the point $(1,1)$ from its starting angle of $\frac\pi4$ to its final angle of $\beta$, which is either a positive rotation or a negative one, depending on the relative sizes of $B$ and $A$.

To get the values of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ you'll need to [solve a SSS triangle](http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/trigonometry/solve_trig_sss.htm).

Comment: What you said I know, I would like the equation of alfa and beta cause (1,1) will eventually be (x,y). I am not lazy, I can do that with your answer but you dont explain how you came out with pi/2 - γ nor with pi/4.

Comment: $\gamma$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and the yellow bar. The initial value for $\gamma$ is $\pi/2$, so the difference is $\pi/2 - \gamma$. Similarly the initial value for $\beta$ is $\pi/4$ because that's the angle between the $x$-axis and the line joining $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$. For the general case where $(1,1)$ becomes $(x,y)$ the initial angle will be $\arctan(y/x)$ instead of $\pi/4$.